# i am trying to implement piechart in my iOS project but getting exception

Tags: ios, pie-chart

```
@synthesize pieChartView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *dataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        NSNumber *number=[NSNumber numberWithInt:rand()%60+20];
        [dataArray addObject:number];
    }

    @try
    {
        [self.pieChartView renderInLayer:self.pieChartView dataArray:dataArray];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",exception);
    }
    @finally
    {

    }
}
```

This is the code I am following from a example code. I tried 2 different examples still ending with the exception error:

> [1948:46071] -[UIView renderInLayer:dataArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff6f840e6c0

Comment: No Need to try and catch Simple write this line  [self.pieChartView renderInLayer:self.pieChartView dataArray:dataArray];

Comment: this is the output am getting even if i write like urs
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView renderInLayer:dataArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f94ac50a1b0'"